C# generated source not actually being generated
I'm working on C# code generation for the first time.   I have what I believe is the correct setup and a functional basic generator, but it doesn't seem to actually be outputting any generated code.
They key parts of my main program look like this:
namespace ArincParser
{
    public static partial class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PrintHello();
        }


        static partial void PrintHello();
    }
}

My generator contains this:
namespace VulcanGenerator
{
    [Generator]
    public class DummyGenerator : ISourceGenerator
    {
        public void Execute(GeneratorExecutionContext context)
        {
            context.AddSource("Dummy.g.cs", @"
namespace ArincParser;

public static partial class Program
{
    public static partial void PrintHello()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(""HELLO\n"");
    }
}
"
            );
        }

        public void Initialize(GeneratorInitializationContext context)
        {
        }
    }
}

The project file for my main project contains this:
  <ProjectReference Include="..\VulcanGenerator\VulcanGenerator.csproj"
                      OutputItemType="Analyzer"
                      ReferenceOutputAssembly="false"/>

The project file for my generator looks like this:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <EnforceExtendedAnalyzerRules>true</EnforceExtendedAnalyzerRules>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers" Version="3.3.4">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp" Version="4.9.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

When I run a build, I see the VulcanGenerator being built, but the generated function does not execute.   I turned on the EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles option, and I see a generated directory in my build output directory now, but there are not any files actually being put into it.
Unsure what I'm missing or how to proceed with debugging this.  Any help that can be provided would be appreciated.   Thanks!

ISourceGenerator is the old version, and no longer recommended. Please switch to IIncrementalGenerator
